# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration while running spark Hbase using java API

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am running simple application to get data from HBase in **Spark** using java API

running **spark-submit command** e.g.

```
bin/spark-submit --master spark://192.168.43.75:7077 --class com.scry.NLPAnnotationController --driver-class-path /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.98.22-hadoop2/conf:$SPARK_HOME/lib_managed/jars/*.jar:$HBASE_CLASSPATH/*.jar --jars $SPARK_HOME/lib_managed/jars/*.jar:$HBASE_CLASSPATH/*.jar /home/deepak/hbase.jar
```

It gives error like

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

In the console where you are running spark-submit, first execute below command and then run spark-submit

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_CLASSPATH

If this works then add this entry in your hadoop-env.sh

Hope it helps...

Comment: I have tried this but getting same error.  in HBASE_CLASSPATH =/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.98.22-hadoop2/lib

Comment: Try to give option as --driver-class-path /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.98.22-hadoop2/conf:$SPARK_HOME/lib_managed/jars:$HBASE_CLASSPATH if it works, also --jars option should be comma separated, so try to give all jars with full path as comma separated like --jars $HBASE_CLASSPATH/first.jar,$HBASE_CLASSPATH/second.jar and so on...